# Нарисовать несколько полилиний (Polyline) с одинаковыми координатами

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Вопрос назрел по причине того, что в API ЯндексКарт так и не вернули тип линии MultiLineString, которая была в старых версиях API.
Суть вопроса заключается в необходимости создания на карте Полилинии состоящей из 4 (8,16,32) линий имеющих одинаковые координаты.
Как это реализовать примерно мне представляется возможным нарисовав одну линию, и потом её размножив до нужного количества, но как это сделать на практике не смог разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понимаю какую практическую задачу вы пытаетесь решить полилиниями с одинаковыми координатами, но вот:

```js
var coords = [
  [55.944695396407490, 37.812260742187470],
  [55.845924887839345, 37.441472167968710],
  [55.771681203187110, 37.806767578124976],
  [55.700397492129970, 37.449711914062476],
  [55.607222137864110, 37.817753906249980],
  [55.538751936723670, 37.419499511718720],
];

ymaps.ready(function () {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', { center: [ 55.75, 37.62 ], zoom: 9 });
  var colors = ['#bdc3fe', '#7a87fd', '#273bfb', '#031197'];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var polyline = new ymaps.Polyline(coords, {}, {
      strokeWidth: Math.pow(i + 2, 2.3),
      strokeColor: colors[i],
      zIndex: 100 - i // тонкие линии должны быть выше
    });
    map.geoObjects.add(polyline);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Задача в том, чтобы по клику на кнопку или выпадающую менюшку самостоятельно нарисовать на карте 4, 8, 16 линий с одинаковыми координатами и одинаковой толщины

Comment: но каждой из этих линий задать уникальный цвет. (Неважно что они будут сливаться и как это будет выглядеть). Главное чтобы они были на карте. В дальнейшем эти линии будут записаны в Базу Данных и на страничку подгружаться уже из этой Базы. Реализация рисования Метки, Линии, Полигона, Круга и занесения их в Базу данных уже реализована и работает. Осталась Мультилиния.

Comment: Тогда вам достаточно просто создавать линии через `new ymaps.Polyline` и добавлять их на карту через `map.geoObjects.add`. Если мой ответ вам помог, то, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за него или отметьте его как лучший (см [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Получается чтобы создать один участок ломанной линии на карте длинной 1 километр с изломами по улицам толщиной в 32 штуки - мне нужно будет 32 раза её нарисовать на карте и каждую в конечном итоге подкрасить в нужный цвет? А мне таких линий толщиной 32, 48, иногда и 64 с одинаковыми координатами нужно километров 500 нарисовать. Такое решение получается из Ваших слов или я Вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите реализовать. Если вам нуна линия "с изломами", то это обычный `ymaps.Polyline`.

Comment: Мне нужно много полилиний, которые я должен нарисовать вручную и каждая такая полилиния должна содержать в себе 4, 8, 16, 32 подполилиний разных цветов.

Comment: Просто создайте несколько `ymaps.Polyline` и добавьте их на карту, как в моем ответе